# Response.Redirect in DNN using CommandArguments

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, response.redirect

I have an imagebutton in ASCX file which code is

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonEdit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemID") %>' ImageUrl="~/images/edit.gif" OnClick="ImageButtonEdit_Click" />`
```

and the behind code is

```
protected void ImageButtonEdit_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton editing = (ImageButton)sender;
    Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID, "AddCollectionItem", "mid=" + this.ModuleId) + "?ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(editing.CommandArgument));
}
```

Problem is it doesn't Redirect to the page or any other thing?
The `Response.Redirect` when I try to use it in general it doesnt work in this part only and in the other site it is working well

Comment: Have you added breakpoints to ensure that the code is being hit? Also maybe hard code in url in Response.Redirect to test.

Comment: yah , it hits the lins but do nothing ,, even when i insert hard code nothing happened

Comment: Could you  use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass a URL with two ?s in it, that might be causing part of the problem. Your second argument, ?ID= should be "&ID="

```
protected void ImageButtonEdit_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton editing = (ImageButton)sender;
    Response.Redirect(Globals.NavigateURL(TabID, "AddCollectionItem", "mid=" + this.ModuleId + "&ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(editing.CommandArgument)));
}
```

You also could pass that inside of NavigateURL instead of outside of NavigateURL as you are doing.

If your module is properly inheriting from PortalModuleBase you don't need PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabID, just call TabID directly.

Also, are you doing any of this inside of an Update Panel? Perhaps that is causing redirect issues?